# How can I Cancel Multiple Background Workers in a For loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, backgroundworker

Creating a Windows app in Visual Studio 15. 
Have a form where I can start up to 10 background worker tasks (BG1 to BG10). I currently cancel each BGWorker individually with:

```
Private Sub DSx10C_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DSx10C.Click
    BackgroundWorker10.CancelAsync()
    BackgroundWorker10.Dispose()
    Label10.Text = "Cancelled"
End Sub
```

I need to do a Cancel ALL option.
How can I loop through all 10 BGWorkers in a For loop?
Hope my question is a better MCVE.

Comment: How do you do anything for multiple objects in a loop?  You put those objects into a list of some sort, e.g. an array, and then you enumerate that list using a `For Each` loop.  Inside the loop, you perform the desired action on the current list item.

Comment: Also, you should not be disposing the `BackgroundWorker` immediately after cancelling it. I think you need to do a bit more reading on how they work. Calling `CancelAsync` does NOT cancel anything. It simply requests a cancellation. Inside the `DoWork` event handler, you still have to write code to check whether a cancellation has been requested and then do whatever is necessary to stop the work you're doing.  The `RunWorkerAsync` event is still raised and that handler will indicate whether the work was completed or cancelled.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889). Post #19 provides a cancellation example.  By the way, why have you added the VBA tag to this question? Also, what has this got to do with WPF? Even if your app is WPF, the question has nothing specific to do with WPF so the tag is irrelevant.  I have removed those irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to cancel all the `BackgroundWorkers`,

You can do it like this:
     Declare an `array` of `BackgroundWorkers`

```
Dim MyBackgroundWorkers() As BackgroundWorker
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '' add all your BackgroundWorkers to the array
    MyBackgroundWorkers = New BackgroundWorker() {BackgroundWorker1, BackgroundWorker2, BackgroundWorker3, BackgroundWorker4, BackgroundWorker5}
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '' now you can Cancel all of them in a loop
    For Each bgw In MyBackgroundWorkers
        If bgw.IsBusy Then
            bgw.CancelAsync()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is assuming that your `BackgroundWorkers` are `controls` you added from the toolbox at design time. If it was declared and added from code, you would need to make appropriate modifications in the `Form_Load` code.

Try This. Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks - works a treat - I do love learning. Do I have to mark as closed somewhere?